# Add parameters to URLs in ezPublish

Tags: ezpublish

I have an url like `$article.url|ezurl(,'full')`, but I need to pass additional parameters to it (eg. `(offset)/2`).

Please note that I am using `attribute_view_gui` for images, so I can't just hardcode it.

I tried creating variables:

```
{def $url = $article.url|ezurl(,'full')}
```

And then adding values there, but it's useless.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add view parameters to the URL before passing it to the `ezurl()` template operator.

```
<a href={concat( $article.url, '/(offset)/2' )|ezurl}>{$article.name|wash}</a>
```

Note that `ezurl` adds double quotes by default so you don't need to add them in your html/tpl code with `<a href="{concat...}">...`

If you want to use a `$url` variable, then you need to tell `ezurl` not to add these quotes :

```
{def $url = concat( $article.url, '/(offset)/2' )|ezurl('no')
     $name = $article.name}
<a href="{$url}">{$name|wash}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "owviewparams" extension to modify, add or remove view parameters from an url : http://projects.ez.no/owviewparams